# Using the Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the Google Admin SDK to get all of the users for a directory on our site but I'm trying to figure out what exactly `page` on line 4 of the code means.

```
function listAllUsers() {
      var pageToken, page;
      do {
        page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
          domain: 'example.com',
          orderBy: 'givenName',
          maxResults: 100,
          pageToken: pageToken
        });
        var users = page.users;
        if (users) {
          for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('No users found.');
        }
        pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
      } while (pageToken);
    }
```

Comment: Did the code work? If results are beyond the `maxResults=100`, then the next batch is processed: `pageToken`.

Comment: No I'm getting an error on line 4 of the code; "resource not found:domain(line four, file "code")".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to do when performing this piece of code.

1. enable the Admin Directory API in the script editor
   [image]
2. enable the Drive SDK from the Google Developers Console
   [image]
   [image]
3. in the Admin console of your Google Apps domain, under Security, enable API access:
   [image]
4. add proper domain name, ie **not** *example.com*

I just tried the following revised code, with my own domain name:

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain: 'jacobjantuinstra.nl'}).users;
  if(users.length != 0) {
    for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
}
```

and the following was shown in the logger:
[image]

The `do while` is meant to restrict each iteration to 100 users. If you have less, or have an execution time of less than 5 minutes, then the above code will suffice.

Comment: Thats great thanks, I got the code to work but it throws up an error for google drive when I published it and embedded it on my site so I have to solve that now!